# How to avoid dropping a wand when grabbing another one

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, actions

I'm working on a character who is going to be using a fair amount of wands.
I'm going to be using [efficient quiver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/efficient-quiver) to carry them around, which also lets me grab the one I want easily.

Here's the bit for the character. I plan on switch wands frequently. Dropping a wand is a free action. But that leaves the wand on the ground at my feet. A very poor location for your item to be. Putting it back in the quiver is a move action which is too much of an action. [Quick draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/quick-draw-combat---final) doesn't work for wands or in reverse either, which is thankfully covered by the quiver.

Is there a way to have it go back into the quiver, say a modification of the throwing weapon property or something? Can weapon cords be attached to each wand so they will just dangle from me or the quiver?

Ideally having the wand go back into the quiver, either at the end of my turn (since wands can't be used for AOO's) or when I am finished with it and want another wand. With the wand going back into the quiver it makes it free to choose again if need be. The alternative is to have them dangling from me and having to spend an action (likely increasing when there are several wands) to find the one I want.

I would even settle for some kind of coat or bandoleer with those [clips which have strings which get pulled back when you let go of what it's holding](http://www.usalanyards.com/a/reel/plain/rotatable/rt-11/all-direction-pull-retractable-cell-phone-string-rt-11-cp-5.jpg).

The reason behind this is that I want/need to be able to "full attack" with a newly drawn wand using the magus ability to cast and attack using a full action. If I lose that ability to draw the wand I need, it will hurt my effectiveness. My ally needs healing, now a buff. Hold on, that debuff is coming!  The Magus can (with a class feature) activate a wand and deliver the spell's Touch Attack through their weapon as a full-round action

Comment: @eimyr: yeah, there's a Magus Arcana for that, hiding in the middle of a honkin' big list. ... Fering: would you be amenable to reframing the question a bit, something like "As a Magus with Wand Wielder, how can I use Spell Combat each round with a different wand/staff without dropping anything?" ... include some of the limitations you've got about the Efficient Quiver and Quick Draw, but remove the implicit requirement that it work for any character in any situation?

Comment: The Efficient Quiver doesn't say anything about reducing the amount of time it takes to draw something from it, only that you'll get the item you're looking for...Unfortunately, the phrase "the quiver can quickly produce any item she wishes" doesn't have any mechanical significance.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is the [Glove of Storing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/glove-of-storing).  The glove lets you store a single item weighing up to 20 pounds in the glove.  Storing or retrieving an item is a free action.  The problem is that one glove of storing takes up both hand slots (preventing you from wearing two).  But it's really the only possible thing I can think of that would allow you to "stow" an item without having to use a move action to retrieve it again.

Then again, for double the cost you could buy a second one that doesn't take up a magic item slot.  Then you'd have two, giving you quick access to four wands at the beginning of a combat.

And finally, if your GM will allow third party materials, there's the [Weapon Juggle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/kobold-press/combat-feats---3rd-party---kobold-press/weapon-juggle-combat) combat feat, which makes sheathing a weapon, picking an item up from the ground, and trading weapons from one hand to another, a free action that does not provoke.

Comment: it was ruled that it is a free action to swap things you are holding in your hands. Sadly 3rd party stuff is not allowed in the game.

Comment: That weapon juggling feat is referring to swapping weapons that are held from hand to hand even when both hands are occupied.  The normal rule to swap items from one hand to another as a free action requires a free hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your GM to allow Weaponwand onto the Permanency list (permanency explicitly says the GM may add any spell they want to the list, allowing RAW to still be in effect for this) you could acquire Gauntlets of the Weaponmaster. This would allow you to use up to 10 weapons with wands permanently inside of them; retrieving a weapon is a swift action and transfers any weapon you're currently holding into the gauntlet.
The only hangup with RAW is, Gauntlets of the Weaponmaster forbids any non-weapon item from being stored inside. This would mean that either the wand would be expelled from the weapon it's currently in, or the weapon would not be allowed into the gauntlet until the wand is removed.